# Pass parameter to jQuery load function in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

I would like to pass an `id` parameter from this action in controller

```
public IActionResult BuildingDetail(int id)
{
  return PartialView("_BuildingDetailsPartial", _buildingRepository.GetById(id));
}
```

into this `load` method in view to run AJAX.

```
@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#LoadBuildingDetail").click(function () {            
            $("#BuildingDetail").load("/employees/buildingdetail/id");              
        });
    })
</script>}
```

I am new to jQuery, but I guess I need to store `id` vaule somehow before passing it into load function, so `controller/action/parameter` approach does not work. But atm I had no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass id to the controller via jquery `load` method, you can pass it directly into the `load` method as an object.

I assume you have the id's value somewhere on the page or you are hardcoding it in the view using razor syntax from your model.

In any case, try using something like this in your jquery

```
//passing id's value from the control on the page
$("#BuildingDetail").load("/employees/buildingdetail", { id: $("#Id").val() });
```

or

```
//passing id's value from the Model property
$("#BuildingDetail").load("/employees/buildingdetail", { id: @Model.Id });
```

Reference: [jQuery load method](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Thanks for response. I am passing something like ViewModel to my view, so I can access `BuildingId` inside `foreach` where I iterate through Model. So the `id` I want, is accessed like this: `@employee.Office.BuildingId`. I tryed your first approach, because I don't know how to pass it as Model property in my scenario.

Comment: So I am storing `BuildingId` inside `input` in each iteration: `<input id="Id" type="hidden" value="@employee.Office.BuildingId" />` but I can only access first value from whole iteration like that. My goal is when I click on a button then BuildingDetails of specific Building which hosts Office of specific Employee appears. Atm It only works when I click on first button to show BuildingDetails. Hope you got what i mean.

Comment: Oh I see. If there are multiple Ids, you can create a function taking the `id` as a parameter and call it on your `#LoadBuildingDetail` click.